# java リソース・リーク'<unassigned Closeable value>'が閉じられることはありません。

Tags: java

```
public class Practice7 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    int num2=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    System.out.println(num1+num2);
  }
}
```

num1とnum2をそれぞれキーボードで入力し、Enterでその合計を表すコードなのですが、
int num1 =...とint num2 =... の2つの行の左に黄色い！マークとライトボルブがついて、
カーソルをそちらに持っていくと、「リソース・リーク'<Unassigned Closeable Value>'が閉じられることはありません。」とでてきます。

何が間違っているのかが分からず、この「リソース...」も理解が出来ないので、教えていただけるとありがたいですm__m

Answer (score 2):

Scannerに対してcloseメソッドが呼ばれていないことに対するメッセージだと思います。

以下のコードならそのメッセージはでるのでしょうか？

```
public static class Practice7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

また、ScannerはAutoClosableを実装しているので、Java7以降であればtry-with-resourceの書き方でもクローズができると思います。